# Exporting Quantmod stock data to excel

Tags: excel, export, quantmod, stocks

I'm trying to export yahoo stock data imported using the getSymbols function to Excel, anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to go: write.csv(Variable, "File_Name", rownames = TRUE)

let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Works fine, doesn't export it in a nice format but the text to columns function in excel fixes that easily. Thanks!